# Weak linking modules

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So think about this project layout:

Top Level > Auth Module
Top Level > Rentals Module > Auth Module

Rentals Module weak links Auth Module, as it needs it to compile. Top Level strong links the Auth Module.

Imagine a scenario when the rentals module version of auth module is outdated.

When I run the app in the simulator, after deleting derived data, my app is using the out of date Auth Module from the Rentals Module and not my latest Auth Module! Why is it pulling this version in if it is weak linked?